# Is it possible to compile the SLATEC library on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, fortran

I'm desperately trying to install the Fortran library SLATEC on my Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6, but I can't make it work. I use the GCC compiler.

My exact steps are:

```
$ mkdir slatec 
$ cd slatec 
$ cp ~/Downloads/slatec_src.tar . 
$ tar xopf slatec_src.tar 
$ cd src
```

In the `src` folder it does not exists any makefile. So I (tried) to download slatec4linux.tar.

```
$ cp ~/Downloads/slatec4linux.tar . 
$ tar xopf slatec4linux.tar
$ cd slatec4linux 
$ sudo make install
```

This does not work. Error message:

```
mv static/libslatec.a /usr/local/lib; \
mv dynamic/libslatec.so /usr/local/lib; ldconfig; \
mv *.1 /usr/local/man/man1
mv: rename static/libslatec.a to /usr/local/lib/libslatec.a: No such   file or directory
mv: rename dynamic/libslatec.so to /usr/local/lib/libslatec.so: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: ldconfig: command not found
mv: rename *.1 to /usr/local/man/man1/*.1: No such file or directory
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

I do not know anyone that have accomplished the installation on a Mac.

Comment: Did you run `./configure` first? Does it fail during the `make` step?

Comment: It is quite possible you have to adjust the makefile by hand. Which compiler are you trying to use? The details are compiler specific.

Comment: Saying *"messages about wrong architecture"* is not useful at all. Please provide the **complete** output of the make command.

Comment: Please do not put any EDIT or SOLVED or anything like that into the question title. The StackOverflow system shows all edits automatically. Try to make your question clear and concise, stay away from "I am a noob" and similar stuff about you, concentrate on the details of the issue.

Comment: Please run `make` first, before `make install`. There is no attempt of compilation in the messages you show. Please note that the errors you spoke about in the first version of the question were very different.

Comment: You mean that I should run the makefile in the folder slatec4linux? 

Running make fist I get the following error:
    cd static; make
    make[1]: *** No rule to make target `../aaaaaa.f', needed by `aaaaaa.o'.  Stop.
    make: *** [libslatec.a] Error 2

Comment: Yes, I meant that and I wanted to see the errors. See the answer by mko anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to install gfortran

http://www.owsiak.org/?p=3492

Make sure to download sources and linux makefile and put all files at the same level.

By saying at the same level, I mean that all `*.f` files from *slatec_src.tgz* and `makefile` and `dynamic` and `static` from *slatec4linux.tgz* are in the same dir.

http://www.netlib.org/slatec/slatec_src.tgz

http://www.netlib.org/slatec/slatec4linux.tgz

Make sure to export FC variable

```
export FC=gfortran
```

Make sure to change this line inside dynamic/makefile

```
libslatec.so: $(OBJ)
  $(CC) -shared -o $@ $(OBJ)
```

to

```
libslatec.so: $(OBJ)
  $(FC) -shared -o $@ $(OBJ)
```

Call make

```
make
```

Wait a little bit. Take a look inside `static` and `dynamic`, files should be there.

```
find . -name "libslatec*"
./dynamic/libslatec.so
./static/libslatec.a
```

Now, you can try to perform `make install` (pay attention here as it will overwrite hardcoded locations). Alternatively, you can use `-L${WHERE_YOUR_BUILD_WAS_DONE}/dynamic -lslatec`

**Installation of LAPAC**

```
mkdir lapack
cd lapack
curl "http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapack-3.7.1.tgz" -o lapack-3.7.1.tgz
tar zxf lapack-3.7.1.tgz
cd lapack-3.7.1
ln -s make.inc.example make.inc
make
```

You will find **liblapack.a** inside *lapack-3.7.1*. You can link it with your code.

Have fun with Fortran!

Comment: Performing the suggested steps following error message is produced after the make-step:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_dlamch_", referenced from:
      _d1mach_ in d1mach.o
  "_slamch_", referenced from:
      _r1mach_ in r1mach.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [libslatec.so] Error 1
make: *** [libslatec.so] Error 2

Comment: Typing: 
    $ make 
in the dir containing all *.f files from slatec_src.tgz and makefile, dynamic, and static from slatec4linux.tgz.

Comment: Aha. Nice. 

Output before error-message: 
gfortran -shared -o libslatec.so aaaaaa.o  cnbdi.o   dcv.o     dqc25f.o  ...(long list of .o-files)..  splpup.o

Comment: Then it seems that my original problem is installing lapack-correctly. What would be the correct configuration in the make.inc file for gfortran? (I tried this (http://www.commonmediainc.com/2008/03/24/building-lapack-and-rubys-linalg-on-mac-os-x/), but I stil get the same error when trying to run make for slatec.

Answer (score 0):

I followed mko's answer but I get the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_dlamch_", referenced from:
      _d1mach_ in d1mach.o
  "_slamch_", referenced from:
      _r1mach_ in r1mach.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Apparently, `dlamch` and `slamch` are procedures from the Lapack library. To fix it in `./dynamic/makefile`, change:

```
libslatec.so: $(OBJ)
    $(FC) -shared -o $@ $(OBJ)
```

to:

```
libslatec.so: $(OBJ)
    $(FC) -L$(WHERE_LAPACK_IS_INSTALLED) -llapack -shared -o $@ $(OBJ)
```